# Is it possible to return from a method using @Advice.OnMethodEnter?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

Using Byte Buddy's advice API, is it possible to return from the instrumented method without actually executing it?

One use case would be to implement a cache and to return the cached value, if present, instead of computing the value again.

```
@Advice.OnMethodEnter
public static Object returnCachedValue(@Advice.Argument(0) String query) {
    if (cache.containsKey(query)) {
        // should "abort" method call
        return cache.get(query);
    }
}
```

I know that this code sample above just creates a local variable which I can get in a `@Advice.OnMethodExit` method. But is there a way to abort the method call on an explicit `return`? If yes, is this also possible for `void` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible, a return value can only be set from exit advice. But it can be emulated by skipping the original method in case that a value already exists and by setting this value from the exit advice in case that the enter advice defines a value:

```
class MyAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodEnter(skipOn = Advice.OnNonDefaultValue.class)
  public static Object returnCachedValue(@Advice.Argument(0) String query) {
    if (cache.containsKey(query)) {
      return cache.get(query);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @Advice.OnMethodExit
  public static void processCachedValue(
          @Advice.Return(readOnly = false, typing = DYNAMIC) Object returned,
          @Advice.Enter Object enter) {
    if (enter != null) {
      returned = enter;
    } else {
      cache.put(query, returned);
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, this does not work if the cached value is `null`. To avoid this, you could wrap the value in some instance to make sure that the enter value is never `null`. Doing so would also allow to use the above pattern to `void` methods.

This might look inconvenient to program but the idea of advice is that Byte Buddy can use the advice class as a template and inline the byte code without much work to avoid a runtime overhead.

Comment: `processCachedValue` declares a return type but doesn't return anything; this code wouldn't compile.